# Building a "tag-editor" like the one here on stackoverflow to add/remove tags - in asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, ajax

For a customer project, I need to be able to add/remove tags from items (pictures in this case).

I really like the way the Add Tag works here in stackoverflow.

[alt text http://sixfootfour.net/images/Tags.png](http://sixfootfour.net/images/Tags.png)

I know how to make the autosuggest-textbox (since there is a control for that in the Ajax Control Toolkit from asp.net), but I am not sure how to approach creating the list of tags, and how to add/remove from it without postbacks.

Should I look into JQuery to solve this, or what should be my approach?

I use Visual Studio 2008 and ASP.NET 3.5.

Comment: Well first I would right-click and "View Source" and then... :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up a web service or page method to add the tags to your database then calling it with asp.net ajax would be an easy solution then combine that with your auto complete box. And you would probably need another method for removing a tag to be called when the user clicks the x.

As for the actual tags, I think you could get that same look by styling an unordered list with a tags for the cross and maybe for the text. Then you could on success add the tag to the list using javascript.

[The official site](http://www.asp.net/ajax/) has some pretty good tutorials.